# Gallery Formatter Adjusting the Width of Gallery-Thumbs

Tags: javascript, media

I am using a Gallery Formatter on my site. The thumbnails are appearing below the main image, the size of thumbs-gallery is exactly the same size as gallery-slides. I actually want thumbs-gallery to appear from one corner of the window to the other. My div which contains this Gallery formatter gallery has 100% width of the document, So I gave the thumbs-gallery the width 100% which does what I want but when I am clicking the arrow to scroll the thumbs it at the end of the thumbs gives a large blank space, on clicking again it starts fine from the start.

Please suggest how to achieve my desired result.

Following is the link of my page on which I am getting problem, just click the arrow to scroll twice to see the problem

http://zgphotographydubai.com/content/industrial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a way to make thumbnails to appear from left edge of the document to the right edge for this I tried to make some CSS tweaks but that do 1 thing right and 2nd thing wrong. So I have tried Galleria Module from its configuration settings I select the width Auto. It did the trick for me. There are several other configuration options available in galleria module which are not available in gallery formatters.

Answer (score 0):

make shure the empty li's have no width specified (or are now shown at all). change

```
<li class="empty" style="width: 121px;"/>
```

to

```
 <li class="empty"/>
```

if you cannot manage that - do it via css

```
.gallery-thumbs li.empty { width: 0px !important; }
```

Comment: not seems to work at my end I have defined this rule in css
.gallery-thumbs li.empty { width: 0px !important; }

Comment: okey - and is it matched ? you could also try .gallery-thumbs li.empty { display: none; }

Comment: both of these actually worked to finish that empty space but this is causing some additional problems like when we click on next previous buttons on the left and right side of big slide image it moves the gallery thumbs in strange way(next previous buttons can currently seen by clicking ctr+A because they are transparent right now)

Comment: so - you need to find out why these empty li are produced .., and try not to do so ..

Comment: I have used Galleria and it resolved my problem

Comment: also a solution ;)